# i want to make a page in magento in which title should be change according to $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php, magento

I want to create a page in Magento where the page title should change according to `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: for each page of magento or for just a single specific page ?

Comment: for a single specific page..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

via code by accessing head block element and calling setTitle('your title') method on it

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle('your title');
```

you can add `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` inSet title argument,

let me know if i can help you further.

Comment: thanks a lot  liyakat  for this information ....i want to call this phtml file in Layout Update XML of my page